# Making a nested function take an id as a variable - Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I created some functions and realized I wanted to have a way to call it multiple times.

How would I rewrite the function so I can also use the js on the second div as well?

https://jsfiddle.net/qj0q3zob/2/

Here is the original code

```
function createRectangles() {
    document.getElementById("homeactualcontent").innerHTML = " ";
    var count = 330;
        for(var i=0; i<count; i++){
            var newRect = document.createElement('div');
            newRect.className = 'rectangle';
            document.getElementById('homeactualcontent').appendChild(newRect);
    }


}

function colorIt() {
    var rects = document.querySelectorAll(".rectangle");
    for(var i=0; i<rects.length; i++){
        var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 220)+30;
        var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30);
        var c = Math.floor(Math.random() * 220)+140;
        var d = Math.random()*1;
        rects[i].style.backgroundColor  = "rgb(" + a + "," + b + "," + c + ")";


    }
}


function moveIt() {
    var rects = document.querySelectorAll("#homeactualcontent .rectangle");
    var area = document.getElementById("homeactualcontent");
    for(var i = 0; i < rects.length; i++) {
        var a = Math.floor(Math.random()*96);
        var b = Math.floor(Math.random()*20);
        var c = Math.floor(Math.random()*90);
        var d = Math.floor(Math.random()*90);

        rects[i].style.position = "absolute";
        rects[i].style.left = a+"%";
        rects[i].style.right = b+"%";
        rects[i].style.top = c+"%";
        rects[i].style.bottom = d+"%";

    }
}
```

I thought that this would work, but I think there might be some syntax errors...or I guess just plain normal errors. Any insight would be great!

Edited code:

```
function rectz(x){

    function createRectangles(x) {
        document.getElementById(x).innerHTML = " ";
        var count = 330;
            for(var i=0; i<count; i++){
                var newRect = document.createElement('div');
                newRect.className = 'rectangle';
                document.getElementById(x).appendChild(newRect);
        }


    }

function colorIt() {
    var rects = document.querySelectorAll(".rectangle");
    for(var i=0; i<rects.length; i++){
        var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 220)+30;
        var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30);
        var c = Math.floor(Math.random() * 220)+140;
        var d = Math.random()*1;
        rects[i].style.backgroundColor  = "rgb(" + a + "," + b + "," + c + ")";


    }
}


function moveIt(x) {
    var rects = document.querySelectorAll(" .rectangle");
    var area = document.getElementById(x);
    for(var i = 0; i < rects.length; i++) {
        var a = Math.floor(Math.random()*96);
        var b = Math.floor(Math.random()*20);
        var c = Math.floor(Math.random()*90);
        var d = Math.floor(Math.random()*90);

        rects[i].style.position = "absolute";
        rects[i].style.left = a+"%";
        rects[i].style.right = b+"%";
        rects[i].style.top = c+"%";
        rects[i].style.bottom = d+"%";

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you ask a more specific question than "Any insight?".  What exactly is your problem?  Where did you get stuck?  What exactly do you need help with?  What do you want to accomplish by changing the code?  I'd suggest you read [How to I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You also aren't showing us how you call the nested function. How is it used?

Comment: Sorry, I want the a div id to be in the function parameter like rectz(div1)